# Highcharts: How to put a line between label and Bubble chart

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I'm using the Highcharts and trying to create a line between data label and a bubble, something like this -> [Image bubble highcharts with a line between data label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUjq7.png)

```
or like `http://jsfiddle.net/u4Lncf4s`
```

It's possible to create that in bubble chart ? because this time I'm not found this option in api of highcharts.

Anybody have an idea ? Thank you.

Comment: There is not an option for this, unfortunately. You could use the renderer() function to draw one yourself: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer